# Word for 'landscape covered in green'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for a word to describe a natural landscape covered in natural green (trees etc).  Like looking at a massive forest viewed from above.

> Two rivers forked in a _______ landscape/scenery etc

Re the comments: I have tried to look for a word that means this, through dictionaries and the like, but cannot find anything.  Originally, I wasn't looking for a direct synonym of *green*, and it was a coincidence when *verdant* appeared.

Comment: Just because there are other bad questions unclosed on this site does not absolve you of our research requirements and using a basic thesaurus. Please take this off-topic discussion to [its chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87928/discussion-on-question-by-lordology-word-for-landscape-covered-in-green) where I’ve moved the discussion to, or better yet [to our meta site](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common word for a green landscape is **verdant**.

> ADJECTIVE 1(of countryside) green with grass or other rich
>   vegetation.
>
> ‘verdant valleys’
>
> 1.1 Of the bright green colour of lush grass. ‘a deep, verdant green’

[Verdant (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/verdant)

Comment: If you don't mind, may I ask that you please meditate upon [this guidance from Jon Ericson](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11731/2085) and then consider expanding this into a proper answer? Jon’s post explains why we prefer answers with actual context and explanations, not mere copying of someone else’s words from some googled reference work without including any new content in your own words. Otherwise we aren’t building up a library of expert answers by creating new content; we’re only showing off our own google-fu and adding nothing to our growing expert library.

Comment: I'd like to delete the answer, but I cannot since it has been selected. Is there any way to bypass that?

Comment: Your wish is granted.

Comment: I’ve reneged on the deletion because of the associated controversy this has stirred up, and also so that you can have the choice to delete it or not as you now see fit.

Comment: @tchrist Can I vote to un-hold this question?

Comment: @Lordology If you have 250 reputation on the site, you can vote to reöpen your own question, yes. But unless and until you actually show your own efforts at basic research, you are unlikely to get many takers since the close reason still applies.  Moreover, by editing it you would automatically nominate it for the Reöpen Review Queue.

Comment: On second thoughts, I'll leave it up and let the community decide how useful it is.

Answer (score 0):

*Verdant* is the word you are looking for.

Comment: If you don't mind, may I ask that you please med­i­tate upon [this guid­ance from Jon Eric­son](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11731/2085) and then con­sider ex­pand­ing this post into a bet­ter an­swer by net­work stan­dards? Jon’s post ex­plains why we pre­fer longer an­swers with ac­tual con­text and rea­soned ex­pla­na­tions. Other­wise we aren’t build­ing up a li­brary of ex­pert an­swers by cre­at­ing new, orig­i­nal con­tent.